# SSL Certificate not updating in Mac Mail

Tags: ssl, certificate, apple-mail

I have a Let's Encrypt daemon running which updates the domain ssl certificates on a regular basis.

I've set up my mail address and it worked happily for a long time but now Mac Mail is not updating the certificate although the certificate is renewed. Which I can see when I open `strongstaff.de` in Firefox and view the certificate information.

Does someone know if this is a known bug in the Mac Mail software or is there a way to update the certificate in MacOSX or do I need to propagate the update somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with Mac OS X. It is *correctly* reporting that the server's certificate has expired, because the server is indeed sending an expired certificate.

> but now Mac Mail is not updating the certificate although the certificate is renewed. Which I can see when I open strongstaff.de in Firefox and view the certificate information

You're looking at the certificate of a completely different service! Firefox is connecting to the HTTP server, but Mac Mail is connecting to the IMAP and SMTP servers. Even if they all run on the same IP address, they're still three separate programs which have separate TLS configurations (and provide their services on different TCP ports).

So your LE renewal daemon was configured to install the new certificate into the *web* server, but it didn't tell the *mail* services about the renewal, and so e.g. Dovecot on `mail.valoric.de:993` (IMAPS) is actually still using an old certificate which expired on the 21th.

You can see this for yourself using `gnutls-cli <host> -p 993` on Linux.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I already thought I'm nuts xD. I restarted my mail sever and it read the new certificate

Comment: Useful comment & diagnostic tool but an inconclusive solution. I experienced the same behavior; two email accounts on my personal domain were continually receiving notifications from mac mail that the cert expired today but in truth, it was renewed a month ago. gnutls-cli from the Linode instance hosting the mail server reported the correct, non-expired, certificate dates (Thank you for revealing this). In order to get my new MacBook to properly reflect the expiry date, I opened up "keychain access" and removed the expired certs. I then restarted the mail client and the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

First, confirm that they are not expired (see my comment under user1686's answer). If they are fine then remove the expired certs:

Open Finder / Applications / Utilities / Keychain Access.app. Remove the expired certificates from the certificates tab. Restart mail client.